# Auto refresh pivot tables VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am responsible for updating an Excel spreadsheet which pulls its information from an Access database on a daily basis. All the data that i need for my excel spreadsheet is available for me and all that i need to do is click the refresh button.

I've sourced a VBA code which serves my purposes for small documents, however, when i open the larger files it doesn't work correctly.  The code opens the workbook specified but does not run its refresh step - it simply saves and closes the document.  I tried to put in time delays to allow time for the refresh but it seems the refresh never actually starts on the bigger files.

Any ideas?  The code i am using is as follows

```
Sub Autorefresh()

Dim Excel
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Excel.Visible = True
Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
Excel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Excel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open("MyWorkbook.xlsx", Password:="MyPassword")
Workbook.RefreshAll
Workbook.Save

Excel.Quit
Set Workbook = Nothing
Set Excel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: complete shot in the dark but isn't "Workbook" already used by VBA to denote the actual workbook object? It probably shouldn't be used as a variable name.  Perhaps dim the Workbook as wb and set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("MyWorkbook.xlsx", Password:="MyPassword") and wb.RefreshAll will get you better results?  Again, just throwing it out there...

Answer (score 0):

Your using workbook which is a VBA predefined object, alter your code slightly:

```
Sub Autorefresh()

Dim Excl
Set Excl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Excl.Visible = True
Excl.DisplayAlerts = False
Excl.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Excl.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set Wbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open("MyWorkbook.xlsx", Password:="MyPassword")
Wbk.RefreshAll
Workbook.Save

Excel.Quit
Set Wbk = Nothing
Set Excl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Or add in extra code between Refresh all and Save as 
`Workbook.RefreshAll` which is the predefined command to refresh the active workbook (after changing your variables).

Comment: I've copied and pasted the code as you suggest and received an error: "Compile error: Method or data member not found" with Excel.Visible = True highlighted.  Could this be because I have spelt Excel whereas you have used Excl?  I made the spelling the same which ran the script but the update still didn't happen.  I receive a different error "Run-Time error '424': Object required.

Comment: change the Excel in the copied code to Excl (missing e). I've edited the code to correct that error.

Comment: Thanks sous2817, i thought that was the problem so i fixed that up and then got the "Run-Time error '424': Object required.

Comment: any other ideas on how i can get the code to do what i want it to?  I'm still unable to complete the refresh.

Comment: @Rath where is it bugging on?

Comment: When i use the code which you/sous provided i get a "Run-Time error '424': Object required."